# Python PyGame score counter incrementing by seconds instead of by 1

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game where the score should increase by 1 every time that 2 sprites collide. Right now the score appears as 0 to begin and then once the collision happens it increments to 39 (sometimes it's 27. The variability in the number makes me think it's incrementing by seconds). Reading some other answers on here made me realize it's most likely an issue of where I have

```
t = f.render("Score = " + str(score), False, black) 
screen.blit(t, (0,0))
```

located in the for loop. But I have tried putting it elsewhere and then the score does not appear on the screen at all.

here is the part of my code that creates the score

```
class Tub(Sprite):   
    def __init__(self):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image.load("tub.bmp").convert_alpha()
        self.image = transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = width/2
        self.rect.y = height - 100       
    def movement(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if keys [pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= dist
        if keys [pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += dist
    def hit(self, target):
        return self.rect.colliderect(target)

class Singlescoop_pink(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image.load("singlescoop_pink.bmp").convert_alpha()
        self.image = transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randint(0, width-100) #random x position, minus 100 so image does not go off screen
        self.rect.y = -600 #start off screen so starting point to fall down is not visible
    def movement(self):
        self.rect.y += 5
        if self.rect.y > height:
            self.kill()


tub = Tub()
sspink = Singlescoop_pink()
sprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(tub, sspink)
score = 0

def game_loop():

    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
                sys.exit()

        if tub.hit(sspink):
            sspink.kill()
            global score
            score += 1

        tub.movement()
        sspink.movement()
        screen.fill(white)
        t = f.render("Score = " + str(score), False, black)
        screen.blit(t, (0,0))
        sprites.update()
        sprites.draw(screen)
        display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
```

Comment: I've done some game programming before but I havent used pygame before so I'm not sure how you're handling the collision, but it may not be to do with incrementing the seconds, but it might be that the sprites are in contact for more than one frame? Remember, if your game is running at 60 fps, it will be running your main game loop 60 times per second, so it might be that your sprites are in contact for more than one frame, incrementing the score multiple times per second.

Comment: that was the problem exactly. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you can just rename your `movement` functions to `update`, and they will be called by `sprites.update()`.

You have to understand that when you call `kill` on a `Sprite`, it does not magically get removed from your game. It will just be removed from all its sprite groups. You call `sspink.kill()`, but the object is still there, living in the `sspink` variable.

And since you call `sspink.movement()`, it will still move (and collide with your other sprite every iteration of the main loop). But it won't be drawn to the screen, because you handle drawing with a sprite group (`sprites.draw(screen)`), and `sspink` was removed from this group.

What you should do is the following:

Create a new sprite group for the falling blocks:

```
blocks = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(sspink)
```

Then, instead of calling `tub.hit(sspink)` to check for a collision (in fact, just remove the `hit` function), use pygame's [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) function:

```
global score
score += len(pygame.sprite.spritecollide(tub, blocks, True))
```

This function will check for collisions between `tub` and sprites in the `blocks` group, and kill the sprites in that group if there's a collision, and then return the sprites that collided with `tub`.

So we just count how many blocks collided (at the moment, it will be at most one, but let's be future-proof) and add that number to the score.

Since `spritecollide` kills the sprites, there are no longer in the `blocks` group, so they are checked for collision only once. And since they are also no longer in the `sprites` group, they will not be updated or drawn to the screen.

In fact, you no longer need `sspink` at all (we abstracted it away) if we construct our groups like this in the beginning:

```
blocks = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(Singlescoop_pink()) 
sprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(tub, *blocks)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed explanation and other PyGame tips. This has fixed my scoring problem. Thank you!!